# Set up a sound client "server"

Tags: alsa, media, mediaplayer

I have a server that its main usage is being all day long up and running and serve some VMs to the web.

I want to be able to play music from the laptop to the speakers that are connected to the server and movies to its screen.

Actually, I want to control the local (on server) music (mpd, it's done), local movies (like mpd for video, probably vlc) and play youtube's audio (and maybe video) from the laptop to server's output

I've done the audio part via pulseaudio net-sinks on another machine but it's not the way that I want to it this time. Pulse is extremely messy and ugly and I don't want to use it under any circumstances (please, no pulse-related questions or answers). ALSA is preferred.